# iPhone restarts frequently whilst tethering via. USB

Tags: iphone, tethering

When tethering via. USB on my iPhone 4 (4.2.1) with my MacBook Pro (10.6.5) I frequently encounter:

- my iPhone freezes with either a black screen (hard reset) or a frozen screen (hard reset)
- my iPhone restarts itself and reestablishes its internet connection

I can go for an hour or two without a problem, or it might happen after a few seconds. There seems to be a correlation between the amount of data I'm pulling and the frequency of the crash.

I'm using Vodafone New Zealand's 3G network. Tethering is a free feature (using our existing data) here, and we don't need to do anything to enable it. Tethering worked a charm on my old iPhone 3G.

The problem seems to be a [common one](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2660823&start=15&tstart=195).

**Has anyone encountered this problem and found a fix, or, has anyone called Apple about it to submit a bug report?**

Comment: hey man iv got the same problem and i didnt find any solution!
i come from italy. we could try a little debugging saying to each other what we have installed on the phone: the software is up to date to 4.3, so this could not be a problem, cuz when u wrote, 4.3 didnt already exist! my iphone is jailbroken! btw it seems to be a data filter or something similar! iv data man installed and wicarrier (a cydia tweak)... but i think they are not involved in it! let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restoring/updating your phone to the newest firmware from apple. (4.3)